# Find element containing partial ID not working properly

Tags: java, selenium

Heres the HTML Code I'm looking at:

```
<div class="table">
      <div class="thead">
      </div>
      <div class="tbody grey-line">
        <div class="trow">
          <div class="tcell left" data-header-val="stuffa">
            <div class="in-line-header">HEADER A</div>
            <span id="idImlookingfor-0-0" class="asdf-asset
                    asdf-text">text1</span>
          </div>
          <div class="tcell right" data-header-val="stuffb">
          </div>
        <div class="trow">
          <div class="tcell left" data-header-val="stuffc">
            <div class="in-line-header">HEADER A</div>
            <span id="idImlookingfor-1-0" class="asdf-asset
                    asdf-text">text2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="tcell right" data-header-val="stuffd">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the selenium code I'm using to try and find the text values:

```
WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='table']"));
List<WebElement> tableRows = baseTable.findElements(By.className("trow"));
WebElement rowEntry1 = tableRows.get(0);
WebElement rowEntry2 = tableRows.get(1);
WebElement tcellLeft1 = rowEntry1.findElement(By.className("tcell"));
WebElement tcellLeft2 = rowEntry2.findElement(By.className("tcell"));
WebElement text1 = tcellLeft1.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'idImlookingfor')]"));
WebElement text2 = tcellLeft2.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'idImlookingfor')]"));

System.out.println("ENTRY 1");
System.out.println(tcellLeft1.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
System.out.println("OUTPUT " + text1.getText());

System.out.println("ENTRY 2");
System.out.println(tcellLeft2.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
System.out.println("OUTPUT " + text2.getText());
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
ENTRY 1
<div class="in-line-header">HEADER A</div>
  <span id="form-idImlookingfor-0-0" class="asdf-asset
               asdf-text">text1</span>
OUTPUT text1


ENTRY 2
<div class="in-line-header">HEADER A</div>
  <span id="form-idImlookingfor-1-0" class="asdf-asset
                asdf-text">text2</span>
OUTPUT text1
```

I'm trying to search multiple rows for the same partial ID. Why is the second entry giving me "text1" here. It should be finding the element from within the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want this to behave as expected while the selector are same for both elements and two elements matching with a selector. In `findElement()` it is very crucial that you provide the unique selector in order to identify the element. With

```
WebElement text1 = tcellLeft1.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'idImlookingfor')]"));
WebElement text2 = tcellLeft2.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'idImlookingfor')]"));
```

you are essentially targeting two elements and your selectors are not unique for any of those intended element.

In this case I would use textbased xpath search if that's static. Such as 
`//span[text()='text1']` for the first element.

Comment: In this case, the text I'm searching for is not static. I am trying to search two separate "tcell"s which have similar id's. I found a solution though, by changing "//" to ".//". It looks like "//" makes it search the entire html file, instead of the html within the element that calls findElement.

Comment: You could write a xpath using header to find the element as well